# Memory leak with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, abpeoplepickerview

I'm using this code to display the contacts in an app.

```
- (IBAction) selectContact:(id)sender {

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonAddressProperty], nil];
    picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

and there is a memory leak, according to instruments. Even if I cancel the person picker like this:

```
- (void) peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
    NSLog(@"peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel");

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

... I got a leak:

[image: memory leak in instruments]

I have found some posts of developers claiming that this is a bug in the SDK and that a bug has already been filed. Can someone confirm that? or point me in the right direction.

Comment: first you can try `build and analyse` to see if it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this goes against logic, and against everything you know, but please trust me on this. Comment out the line that releases the picker;

```
//-- [picker release]; this line must be commented
```

It's most likely a bug in the Apple SDK

Comment: In an ARC project, you can't comment that out, though, because it's not there and the system does it for you. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your SDK to the most recent iOS version, and see if the leak still occurs.  If it does, please file a bug through the developer center.